# $f(z)$ has a pole if $\lim_{z\to a}\, f(z) = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

here is the statement that I've found in 2 books:

> If $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$, the point $a$ is said to be *a pole* of $f(z)$, and we set $f(a) = \infty$

Intuitively I understand about pole. For example $\frac{1}{z-2}$ has a simple pole at the point $2$. But I don't know how do we get $\infty$ when we take the limit $z$ goes to $2$ since in the real plane this function has no limit cz the left and the right side of limit aren't the same. That's my point. So, how does it have $\infty$ as its limit if that function itself has a pole in the complex plane? So, What's the meaning of that statement actually?

It's been a year I didn't study about complex analysis. Hope you can help me to understand this.

Thanks.

Comment: While $\Bbb R$ is commonly extended by two infinities, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, we extend $\Bbb C$ with only one infinity $\infty$ (thus wrapping the plane into a sphere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like the one-point compactification of $\mathbb C$. The topology on $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ is $\{X:X\subseteq \mathbb C\text { and $X$ is open, or $X^c$ is compact}\}$. Then you can verify that $\lim_{z\to a} f(z)=\infty$ iff $\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)|=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$ means $\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)|=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is non-zero in a punctured neighbourhood of $a$, we can conclude $$\lim_{z\to a}\frac 1{f(z)}=0.$$